# How can I keep the comments at the same line when reformatting the code with Rust code formatter?

Tags: rust, format

I use rust-analyzer in Visual Studio Code with all default settings.

When I press reformat-hot-key,
my comments move away from the same line of code,
which is really not good-looking.

If the comments are at the same line of code,
reading the code will be much more fluent, making the comments an optional read.

The code I wish when reformatting:

```rust
fn main() {
    let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {// :u32 : type casting, work with .parse()
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err(_) => { //_  means any error
            println!("Please input numbers!");
            continue;
        }
    };
}
```

The code I don't like when reformatting:

```rust
fn main() {
    let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
        // :u32 : type casting, work with .parse()
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err(_) => {
            //_  means any error
            println!("Please input numbers!");
            continue;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Not related to VSCode as such. This is done by the rust formatter.
Please tell us which formatter you're using so we can point you to the corresponding config.

Comment: also mention that I opened an issue on github rustfmt repo about this question .https://github.com/rust-lang/rustfmt/issues/5856

Comment: I see that this hasn't been addressed in the rustfmt (as per the link you attached), but there is this old post on rust-lang/style-team: https://github.com/rust-lang/style-team/issues/17

Comment: In short:
// ... style comments must be used for new-line comments,
/* ... */ style comments can be used inline.

Sorry, can't try this myself but it might help